# Call a function of the importer

Tags: python

I'm new to Python, and trying to create a module. Everything went fine, until I had to call a function of the file that is calling this module. I used to pass the function as an argument, and it worked:

```
def my_function(..., ..., func, ..., ...):
```

Then I could call it as:

```
func()
```

But I realized that the function name should not change in my particular case, and that it should always call the same function, like always call `update()`

I tried omitting the argument and instead calling the function like normal, as if the function was in the same module. It didn't work. I also tried using `exec`, but it didn't work either. I'm not really sure how to use `getattr()` because the first argument can vary based on the module name.

How do I call a function of the importer? (Sorry if the title is confusing)

Comment: What happens if your module is imported from several different sites? Will you have `my_function()` call always the first `update()`?

Comment: Imported module has no knowledge of what is importing it so it's impossible. You have to pass callable object explicitly.

Comment: @rodrigo Not sure what you mean. On the top of my other file, I have `from modulename import *` and I want to call the update() function of that  specific importer. In order words, I want to call the update() of the module of the function that called myfunction().

Comment: Better follow some tutorials before putting up a question here . In python each .py file could be used as a module only you need to use import filename (note : not the .py extension) . Later You can call it like moduleName.Func.. Or look for from ModuleName import something. .

Comment: @MakIndia That's not my question. Read it again.

Comment: Can the one who downvoted the question please explain why he/she did it? I could improve the question, you know.

Comment: Why can't you pass `update` to `myfunction` when you call it in the module that's doing the importing? I'm not totally clear on what you're trying to do (a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help) but it sounds like what you want to do goes against the spirit of modular design - a module should be a black box, oblivious to what goes on outside itself. There may be a way to do what you're trying to do, but I suspect that it would be _much_ better to reorganize your design a little.

Comment: FWIW, it's generally considered bad design to pollute your namespace by doing `from modulename import *` in a normal script. That syntax is handy in the interactive interpreter, and may be necessary in the `__init__.py` file of a package, but it should be avoided in an ordinary Python script.

Comment: @PM2Ring The thing I'm making is actually some sort of game engine, but not quite. Something like a bunch of helpful functions related to game development in one spot, that's why I did `from modulename import *`. To make it simpler, and make myself not use `modulename.function`, I decided to import all. Not sure if this is a good idea, but it works.

Comment: You _could_ define a function eg `custom_update()` in the importing module and then do `modulename.update = custom_update` in the global scope of that module (eg straight after the function definition). Then any references to `update` in the imported `modulename` will use your custom function. But it would be _much_ better to reorganize your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way that a function can know what imported it (except possibly via some extremely horrible stack inspection, which you absolutely don't want to do). I don't know why you would think that referring the function as if it was in the same module would work; as you state, it is not in the same module.

I can't help thinking that what you want here is a class: you need to send both some data and a function, so those should be wrapped up in a class instance which you send instead.